# Counting number of lines in my text file from java and outputting the total points scores

Tags: java, arrays, file-io, text-files

I have a text file that is showing the scores of a variety of rugby matches, my code reads the text file, outputs the results of the rugby matches, I need to output how many rugby matches were played. How can I do this? I also need to output how many points in total were scored from all of the rugby matches.

Comment: Can't you just have an `int` variable that starts at 0 and increases by 1 every time you read a line; and another one that starts at 0 and increases by the total score in the game as you read each line?

Comment: Give us your example code and also example txt data, for this to be constructive. Otherwise, this seems as a trivial issue, looping through a txt file and increasing an integer.

Comment: Use a [`LineNumberReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html)?